# Jenkins: Build and push a docker image on Windows

Tags: docker, jenkins

How can I build and push a docker image using Jenkins?

I have the following pipeline that is executed on a Windows 10 Jenkins slave with Windows docker installed.

```
node("windows_10_pro_n_vs2017") {

checkout scm

def app

stage('Build image') {
    /* This builds the actual image; synonymous to
     * docker build on the command line */

    app = docker.build("simmarn/emma2html:win -f docker-windows/Dockerfile .")
}

stage('Push image') {
    /* Finally, we'll push the image with two tags:
     * First, the incremental build number from Jenkins
     * Second, the 'win' tag.
     * Pushing multiple tags is cheap, as all the layers are reused. */
    docker.withRegistry('https://registry.hub.docker.com', 'docker-hub-credentials') {
        app.push("${env.BUILD_NUMBER}")
        app.push("win")
    }
}
```

}

But the build fails without any useful information:

```
        Started by user ...
    23:32:31 Connecting to https://api.github.com using .../****** (GitHub Access Token)
    Obtained Jenkinsfile from ...
    Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
    [Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
    [Pipeline] node
    Running on win1 in C:\jenkins\workspace\emma2html_master
    [Pipeline] {
    [Pipeline] checkout
    using credential github
....
    [Pipeline] stage
    [Pipeline] { (Build image)
    [Pipeline] sh
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // stage
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // node
    [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
```

I guess docker.build and docker.withRegistry are for Linux docker. Is there an adaptation for Windows docker?

I get the following error on Blue Ocean:

Cannot run program "nohup" (in directory "C:\jenkins\workspace\emma2html_master"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

/Martin

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I only needed to update the docker-pipeline plugin in order to get it to work.